# Alert (getElementById) jquery equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I know a bit of javascript, but I'm trying to learn jquery, which seems quite a bit easier. I'm just trying a simple thing, as follows:

`alert( document.getElementById("email").getAttribute('placeholder') );`

Now apparently jquery can use css selectors so, I thought the following would work:

`alert( $("#email").getAttribute('placeholder') );`

But it doesn't. What am I doing wrong? It's probably such a simple answer, but from searching around I can't seem to find it. You might be able to tell that I'm an absolute beginner.

Comment: `getAttribute` is a native DOM method, not a jQuery method. It almost never works to use DOM methods on jQuery objects, jQuery has a different name for everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) function (`$` for short) returns an collection of matching elements, so you'd have to get the first item like this:

```
alert( $("#email")[0].getAttribute('placeholder') );
```

Or you could use the [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function:

```
alert( $("#email").attr('placeholder') );
```

Comment: Ok... makes sense, but seems annoying that it's like that. So if there are multiple elements with the id of #email which one will it use?

Comment: @eshellborn Well, you should never have multiple elements with the same id in one HTML document, but from the jQuery docs, the `.attr` function will "*get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements.*"

Answer (score 3):

You're creating a jQuery object by using `$()` not a JavaScript object here. `document.getElementById()` would have created a JavaScript object for you.

So that won't work

```
alert( $("#email").getAttribute('placeholder') );
```

It would try to think that the object being passed is a JavaScript object, but it isn't so error in the code.

You can change that code to

```
alert( $("#email").attr('placeholder') );
```

Now this would get the `attr` property of the jQuery object from the document. `attr` is a jQuery method to get some value for some attribute of a jQuery object.

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
alert( $("#email").attr('placeholder') );
// or
alert( $("#email").prop('placeholder') );
```

**NEW : Example** : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6Qn9/)

**EDIT :**

There is a `prop` `jquery` function for example if you font to see if element is checked :

let's say that you have html like this `<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />`

```
$( elem ).prop( "checked" ) // return true or false
$( elem ).attr( "checked" ) // return "checked" if there is that attribute
```

This is behaviour in case of `value` or `checked` attribute, in other cases it will do the same as `attr` function.